# Excel VBA code reads some rows and discards others

Tags: vba, excel, backend

this is my first time asking a question here.
so here is my issue:
i have a quite large vba code but i will give you a brief summary of it.

i have a a sheet that contains info about courses, eg: course code, subject, prof, day,btime,etime, etc... 
and another sheet that has the courses that i am looking for to create a schedule.

so the code will read both sheets and compare them and then output the data on another sheet. the problem is that if lets say a course had 2 lectures, 3 tutorials and 2 labs (on different times and days), it will only read some and leave the rest

here is my main code:

```
Sub Schedule()
    Row = 1
    T8 = 1
    T9 = 1
    T10 = 1
    T11 = 1
    T12 = 1
    T13 = 1
    T14 = 1
    T15 = 1
    T16 = 1
    T17 = 1
    T18 = 1
    lRow = Worksheets("Banner Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Schedule").Range("B8:AZ100").ClearContents
    Worksheets("Schedule").Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    Worksheets("Schedule").Activate
    For x = 2 To 7
        For i = 2 To lRow   
            word = Worksheets("Program Map").Cells(5, x)
            PSub = Left(word, 4)
            PCode = Trim(PSub)
            pcourse = Mid(word, 5, 6)
            f = InStr(pcourse, "U")
            PCode1 = Left(pcourse, f)
            day = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 15).Text
            bTime = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 16).Text
            eTime = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 17).Text
            Subject = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 2).Text
            Course = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 3).Text
            Title = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 4).Text
            Section = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 5).Text
            CRN = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 6).Text
            ClassType = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 9).Text
            Room = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 18).Text
            Prof = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 20).Text
            BSubject = Worksheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 2)
            BCourse = Worksheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 3)
            BCode = BSubject & " " & BCourse
            info = Prof & "-" & Subject & " " & Course & "-" & vbNewLine & Title & vbNewLine & CRN & "-" & ClassType & "-" & Section & vbNewLine & Room & ":" & bTime & "-" & eTime 
            RColor = RGB(Int((255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0), Int((255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0), Int((255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0))      
            fcourse1 = PCode & PCode1
            BCourse1 = Subject & Course
            fcourse = Left(word, 10)
            BCourse = Subject & " " & Course

            result = StrComp(fcourse, BCourse)
            result1 = StrComp(fcourse1, BCourse1)
            If result = 0 Then            
                Select Case day
                    Case "M"
                        Call caseM(i)
                    Case "T"
                        Call caseT(i)
                    Case "W"
                        Call caseW(i)
                    Case "R"
                        Call caseR(i)
                    Case "F"
                        Call caseF(i)
                End Select             
            ElseIf result1 = 0 Then
                Select Case day
                    Case "M"
                        Call caseM(i)
                    Case "T"
                        Call caseT(i)
                    Case "W"
                        Call caseW(i)
                    Case "R"
                        Call caseR(i)
                    Case "F"                   
                        Call caseF(i)
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
    Next x      
End Sub
```

just a brief explanation the cases are the days, and the (5, x) is the row in the program map im trying to get the schedule for.

and here is how only the data for ONE DAY and ONE TIME SLOT is processed:

```
Sub caseM(i As Variant)
    day = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 15).Text
    bTime = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 16).Text
    eTime = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 17).Text
    Subject = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 2).Text
    Course = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 3).Text
    Title = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 4).Text
    Section = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 5).Text
    CRN = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 6).Text
    ClassType = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 9).Text
    Room = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 18).Text
    Prof = Sheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 20).Text
    BSubject = Worksheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 2)
    BCourse = Worksheets("Banner Summary").Cells(i, 3)
    BCode = BSubject & " " & BCourse
    info = Prof & "-" & Subject & " " & Course & "-" & vbNewLine & Title & vbNewLine & CRN & "-" & ClassType & "-" & Section & vbNewLine & Room & ":" & bTime & "-" & eTime
    RColor = RGB(Int((255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0), Int((255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0), Int((255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0))
    Select Case bTime
        Case "0810"
            If eTime = "0900" Then
                If T8 = 1 Then
                    If Cells(8, 2) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 2) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("B8").Value = info
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("B8:B12").Interior.Color = RColor
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    Else
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf T8 = 2 Then
                    If Cells(8, 3) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 3) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("C8").Value = info
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("C8:C12").Interior.Color = RColor
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    Else
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf T8 = 3 Then
                    If Cells(8, 4) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 4) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("D8").Value = info
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("D8:D12").Interior.Color = RColor
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    Else
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf T8 = 4 Then
                    If Cells(8, 5) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 5) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("E8").Value = info
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("E8:E12").Interior.Color = RColor
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    Else
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf T8 = 5 Then
                    If Cells(8, 6) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 6) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("F8").Value = info
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("F8:F12").Interior.Color = RColor
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    Else
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf T8 = 6 Then
                    If Cells(8, 7) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 7) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("G8").Value = info
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("G8:G12").Interior.Color = RColor
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    Else
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf T8 = 7 Then
                    If Cells(8, 8) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 8) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("F8").Value = info
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("F8:F12").Interior.Color = RColor
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    Else
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf T8 = 8 Then
                    If Cells(8, 9) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 9) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("F8").Value = info
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("F8:F12").Interior.Color = RColor
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    Else
                        T8 = T8 + 1
                    End If
                End If
```

how this works is that for a certain btime it will check if the cells required for that time and day is empty by checking the color of the cell. and for some reason even if the cell had no color it would still skip it and go on to the next one.

i know that this is long but i have been battling this thing for over a month now, and really need some help. thanks in advance for anyone who does.

Comment: Please reindent your second code block?

Comment: You have `Select Case bTime` but then just goes into many `if` statements....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I found in your code is this part

```
If Cells(8, 2) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 2) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
```

Cells will grab the value of the pointed cell. And you are comparing it with **RGB(0, 0, 0)**

This will always end up false, unless your cell is empty or 0

(RGB(0, 0, 0) Value is 0, and When cells is empty, VBA will consider it as 0)

If you want to compare the actual color, you need to put either

```
Cells(8, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Cells(8, 2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

---

In addition, shorter the code, easier to trouble shoot.

Below part

```
        If result = 0 Then            
            Select Case day
                Case "M"
                    Call caseM(i)
                Case "T"
                    Call caseT(i)
                Case "W"
                    Call caseW(i)
                Case "R"
                    Call caseR(i)
                Case "F"
                    Call caseF(i)
            End Select             
        ElseIf result1 = 0 Then
            Select Case day
                Case "M"
                    Call caseM(i)
                Case "T"
                    Call caseT(i)
                Case "W"
                    Call caseW(i)
                Case "R"
                    Call caseR(i)
                Case "F"                   
                    Call caseF(i)
            End Select
        End If
```

Since you are doing the exact same procedures, you can write it as

```
        If result = 0 or result1 = 0Then            
            Select Case day
                Case "M": Call caseM(i)
                Case "T": Call caseT(i)
                Case "W": Call caseW(i)
                Case "R": Call caseR(i)
                Case "F": Call caseF(i)
            End Select             
        End If
```

Note : **":"** means after **":"** will be considered nextline

---

Also the below part

```
If T8 = 1 Then
    If Cells(8, 2) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 2) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
        Sheets("Schedule").Range("B8").Value = info
        Sheets("Schedule").Range("B8:B12").Interior.Color = RColor
        T8 = T8 + 1
    Else
        T8 = T8 + 1
    End If
ElseIf T8 = 2 Then
    If Cells(8, 3) = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, 3) = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
        Sheets("Schedule").Range("C8").Value = info
        Sheets("Schedule").Range("C8:C12").Interior.Color = RColor
        T8 = T8 + 1
    Else
        T8 = T8 + 1
    End If
...........
```

Can be rewritten as

```
If Cells(8, T8 + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells(12, T8 + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0,) Then
    Sheets("Schedule").Cells(8, T8 + 1).Value = info
    Sheets("Schedule").Range(Cells(8, T8 + 1),Cells(12, T8 + 1)).Interior.Color = RColor
End if
T8 = T8 + 1
```

Comment: This info looks quote useful i'll try it out and get back to you asap, than you very much.

Comment: Hey MutjatLee, again i wanna thank you for your help, but although to me the code that you gave me looks solid and should work properly yet now that i run it to find the schedule on a Monday it literally skips any course that has Monday for its day, any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: for other days, although it skips on a bunch of classes but it still outputs quote alot so im not sure how to deal with this :((

Comment: That means either it's not getting source right, or output is wrong. What I am going to suggest is that on your Macro, Press F8. this will run macro line one by one. and you can move your mouse over to certain variables (Ex. **i**) then it will show you what **i** value is. That is how you trouble shoot your code if it's getting or outputting right value.